# Does AVPlayer support webm URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, avplayer, webm

I have created player in iOS. It works well for URLs such as mp4 and m3u8.
But I have one webm extension URL. AVPlayer is not working for this.

Sample url:

> http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/dead_trees_146.webm

Is there any reason? Or can we make something possible to play this url?

Answer (score 7):

From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html):

> iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:
>
> H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in Audio Technologies.

It doesn't support WebM. You may try using a library like [OGVKit](https://github.com/brion/OGVKit) to play WebM videos.